# Devise "successfully signed in" flash message repeats when user navigates away and then back using back-arrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, flash-message

In my rails app Devise sends a flash message "Successfully signed in" after the user logs in. However if the user navigates to any other page and then navigates back to the post-sign-in page using the back button, the same flash message renders again. Shouldn't it be destroyed automatically after it rendered the first time? How do I keep it from appearing again?